# How can I refer to a named UIColor located in package library's Assets.xcassets?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have list of named color re-inside package library's Assets.xcassets

[image]

### SwiftUI.Color

For SwiftUI.Color, I can access them without issue.

```
SwiftUI.Color("whiteNoteColor", bundle: .module)
```

### UIColor

However, how about `UIColor`?

I have tried the following but it doesn't work

```
UIColor(named: "whiteNoteColor")!
```

Does anyone know, how can I refer to a named UIColor located in package library's Assets.xcassets?

Comment: Did you try the `UIColor init(named:in:compatibleWith:)` initializer?

Comment: Nope. I look at the API, but I have no idea how I should construct a Bundle to refer to the package library.

Comment: Wouldn't it be the same bundle you used for the SwiftUI `Color` initializer?

Answer (score 0):

If you add an `extension` to the Package You can access it directly.

```
extension UIColor{
    static let whiteNoteColor: UIColor = UIColor(named: "whiteNoteColor")!
}
```

You can access `UIColor.whiteNoteColor` when you `import YourPackage`